# Error in python code that scrapes a website using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I created code in python to scrape a file for each item from a website using Selenium. Sometimes the file I am copying does not exist for an item. I need the code to have an output statement to indicate when it does not and to skip the item when the file does not exist.

Below is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver  # use selenium webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By  # allows you to use the by function
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import requests
import os

folder_path = "C:\\Users\\tteme_ohklha0\\Downloads\\retry"

if not os.path.exists(folder_path):
    os.makedirs(folder_path)  # make a folder if not exist

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

starting_url = "https://vtm.navyfst.com/"
n = 0
num = 52
nf = 0

for page in range(1, num + 1):  # goes from page one to 2 with addition of the 1
    cab = 0  # number of capabilities brochures
    n += 1
    print("Page", n)
    page_url = f"{starting_url}?page={page}"  # f allows to create dyanmic strings where you can add variables/expressions
    driver.get(page_url)

    button_details = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'bg-vtm_blue') and text()='Details']")

    for button in button_details:
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", button)
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 25)
        try:
            link_element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Capabilities Brochure")))
            cab += 1
            link_url = link_element.get_attribute("href")
            file_name = link_url.split("/")[-1] + ".pdf"
            response = requests.get(link_url)  # download the file
            save_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)
            with open(save_path, "wb") as file:
                file.write(response.content)
        except TimeoutException:
            nf += 1
            print("No Capabilities Brochure")
    print("Not Found", nf)
    print("Capabilities Brochure", cab)
    print("Page", n, "complete")
```

I wrote an output statement to notify me when the item does not have the file that I want to copy. I also have it skip the item when the file does not exist using a try-except statement. However, when I run the code, even though there is no file that exists for an item, the code does not produce an output statement. The code also skips the last item of each page for some odd reason. I cannot figure out how to fix these errors. Thanks in advance to all those who help.

Comment: XPath for the `button_details`  variable in the outer loop is incorrect, which is why the inner loop isn't getting executed.

Comment: I am able to run the code, and it does copy files, just not always. Why is the button_details incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you don't close the section containing *Capabilities Brochure*. Since you don't close it, it's always visible and there is never exception if first button/loop passes.

```
...
    for button in button_details:
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
        try:
            link_element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Capabilities Brochure")))
            company = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".text-white.text-xl.mb-4").get_attribute('innerText')
            print(company)
            cab += 1
            link_url = link_element.get_attribute("href")
            file_name = link_url.split("/")[-1] + ".pdf"
            # response = requests.get(link_url)  # download the file
            # save_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)
            # with open(save_path, "wb") as file:
            #     file.write(response.content)
            cross = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.fixed.top-8.left-8')))
            cross.click()
            wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element(cross))
        except TimeoutException:
            nf += 1
            print(f"No Capabilities Brochure for {company}")
...
```

Here, it waits till cross appears, clicks it then waits till it's invisible. `button` is clicked using JS, so not scrolled to it. I commented out the `requests` part and added `company` part to check if it's working. There are some sections which do not have *Capabilities Brochure* and hence triggers *TimeoutException*.